# How to add fragment with in tab

Tags: android, android-fragments

public class TabFragment extends Fragment {

```
private TabHost mTabHost;
View rootView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tabinterview, container, false);
    mTabHost = (TabHost) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tabhost);
    mTabHost.setup();
    TabHost.TabSpec spec = mTabHost.newTabSpec("tag");
    spec.setIndicator("Android");
    spec.setContent(new TabHost.TabContentFactory() {

        @Override
        public View createTabContent(String tag) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return (new QuestionFragment().getView());
        }
    });
    mTabHost.addTab(spec);

    return rootView;
}
```

}

In above Code i have created tab and Within tabs i have to add respective fragments 
i had checkout  tabs are shown in fragment but when i try to add set content of tab Question fragment i got the following error

```
07-10 11:00:26.030: E/AndroidRuntime(1025): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-10 11:00:26.030: E/AndroidRuntime(1025): java.lang.NullPointerException
07-10 11:00:26.030: E/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at android.widget.TabHost$FactoryContentStrategy.getContentView(TabHost.java:720)
07-10 11:00:26.030: E/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at android.widget.TabHost.setCurrentTab(TabHost.java:413)
07-10 11:00:26.030: E/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at android.widget.TabHost$2.onTabSelectionChanged(TabHost.java:154)
07-10 11:00:26.030: E/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at android.widget.TabWidget$TabClickListener.onClick(TabWidget.java:546)
07-10 11:00:26.030: E/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4204)
07-10 11:00:26.030: E/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17355)
07-10 11:00:26.030: E/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
07-10 11:00:26.030: E/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
07-10 11:00:26.030: E/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-10 11:00:26.030: E/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
07-10 11:00:26.030: E/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-10 11:00:26.030: E/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-10 11:00:26.030: E/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
07-10 11:00:26.030: E/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
07-10 11:00:26.030: E/AndroidRuntime(1025):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Please help me to add fragment in tabs or suggest me any other logic

your prompt response will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for tabbar concept like this.

[image]

For that i you can use below links.

https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator

Easy to implement.
http://thorbek.net/online/2013/09/01/sliding-windows-with-tab-bar-in-android-activity/

http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/537

this below link is for viewpage indicator
http://viewpagerindicator.com/

Comment: Actually in  my project i had used single activity with sliding menu in that i have multiple option and if you choose any one of the option
Its respective fragment  will shown in same activity now above code is one of my fragment that will open and its is tab style fragment and again i want to add fragment as a content of tabs.

Comment: true. for that you have to use viewpager in each page you have put fragment with indicator.Above link give you example of viewpager with indicator.

Comment: @Nawaf I think you need to think of something else. Tabs in a fragment is not a good design. If you still wish to work with tabs, call another activity on the item click of your side menu and then In that deal with viewpagers. ViewPagers in itself hold fragments, so a ViewPager in a fragment and then multiple fragments in that viewpager is like a HORROR STORY!

Comment: can we  load ViewPager dynamically within activty

Comment: @BhaveshJethani can we load viewpager just like fragment in an activity

Comment: we have to define viewpager inside your fragment layout. then again we have to write code for viewpager.